# Git pull merged wrong branch with octopus strategy

Tags: git

I've been working on `feature` branch forked from `release` branch. And I decided to switch branches so I did:

```
git commit -a
git push
git checkout release
```

Release branch was 20 commits behind and message stated it could be fast forwarded. I did `git pull` and got output:

```
Fast-forwarding to: 10b836074b97d2b3a41690c6d92551922d77b256
Trying simple merge with f0c7df27be7bb118818732a9f92c37da1b1e2b04
Simple merge did not work, trying automatic merge.
Auto-merging app/index.html
Merge made by the 'octopus' strategy.
```

This merged feature branch which I was previously working on into release branch:

```
Merge branches 'feature' and 'release-1.1.46' of ssh** into release-1.1.46
```

Does anyone knows why this happened?

Comment: You must have run `git pull origin feature release-1.1.46`, not just `git pull`. I recommend never using `git pull` at all: break it up into `git fetch` followed by `git merge` and you won't make this mistake ever again.

Comment: @torek no I didn't run this command. I checked it few times if something I did was wrong. Task desc was copied from cli. Strange thing, thats why I came here at the first place

Comment: The only way to get an octopus merge is to run `git merge` with at least two other branch or hash identifiers. The `git pull` command *shouldn't* do this unless you provide two branch names. What does `git config --list` print? (This is too long to fit in a comment, you'll need to edit it into the question. The `branch.release.<whatever>` settings are the main ones of interest.)

Comment: Unfortunately, I just had exactly the same thing happen to me. I ran `git checkout master` from my feature branch, then `git pull` and it merged my feature branch into the master using the octopus strategy.